# How do I troubleshoot this wsimport error in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, wsimport

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.4 with Java 1.6.0_22.  I have a web application that connects to an application server (GlassFish v3) via JAX-WS.  During the "Clean and Build" process, wsimport is called to import the stored WSDL files.  For some reason, I can only successfully perform a "Clean and Build" once after starting NetBeans.  Every subsequent attempt fails with this error:

```
init:
undeploy-clean:
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/build
Deleting directory /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/dist
check-clean:
clean:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
wsimport-init:
Created dir: /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/build/generated-sources/jax-ws
wsimport-client-ChartDataService:
Created dir: /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/build/generated/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService
command line: wsimport -d /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/build/generated/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService -extension -Xnocompile -Xendorsed -keep -s /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/build/generated/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService -catalog /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/catalog.xml -verbose /Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/src/conf/xml-resources/web-service-references/ChartDataService/wsdl/dev_8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService.wsdl -p name.justinthomas.flower.analysis.services.ChartData -wsdllocation http://dev:8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService?wsdl
/Users/justin/Development/flower_vs/nbproject/jaxws-build.xml:31: Error starting wsimport: 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

The noted line is the "wsimport" directive in this target:

```
<target name="wsimport-client-ChartDataService" depends="wsimport-init">
  <mkdir dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService"/>
  <wsimport sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService" destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService" wsdl="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-service-references/ChartDataService/wsdl/dev_8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService.wsdl" catalog="catalog.xml" extension="true" verbose="true" wsdlLocation="http://dev:8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService?wsdl" xnocompile="true" xendorsed="true" package="name.justinthomas.flower.analysis.services.ChartData">
    <depends file="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-service-references/ChartDataService/wsdl/dev_8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService.wsdl"/>
    <produces dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService"/>
  </wsimport>
  <copy todir="${build.generated.sources.dir}/jax-ws">
    <fileset dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService">
       <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

I can run the wsimport line manually (copy and pasted) from the command line successfully.  When I do so, NetBeans then errors on the next web service target.

To correct this error, I have to close NetBeans and restart.  Once I do that, I can once again perform one "Clean and Build" before I'm stuck again.

I only see this problem on my Mac - my NetBeans install on Windows 7 does not have this problem, but I can't find any differences in the configuration that might account for the Mac problems.

It's clear that the error message I'm getting for wsimport is woefully unhelpful.  I can't seem to figure out how to get more verbose error messages to figure out what is actually going on.  Do you know how I might do that?  I'm guessing that a library is being loaded that is causing a conflict, but I don't know where to start in tracking down where that problem is.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same error.  To fix it all I did was remove

```
catalog="catalog.xml"
```

from the wsimport tag attributes and so far I have not had any problems, I can clean and build as often as I want in NetBeans 6.9. Yours would look like this:

```
<target name="wsimport-client-ChartDataService" depends="wsimport-init">
  <mkdir dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService"/>
  <wsimport sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService"   destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService" wsdl="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-service-references/ChartDataService/wsdl/dev_8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService.wsdl" extension="true" verbose="true" wsdlLocation="http://dev:8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService?wsdl" xnocompile="true" xendorsed="true" package="name.justinthomas.flower.analysis.services.ChartData">
    <depends file="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-service-references/ChartDataService/wsdl/dev_8080/flower/analysis/ChartDataService.wsdl"/>
    <produces dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService"/>
  </wsimport>
  <copy todir="${build.generated.sources.dir}/jax-ws">
  <fileset dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ChartDataService">
     <include name="**/*.java"/>
   </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```